# Using Vuex with dynamically created components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to use Vuex to manage dynamically created components. In my app, I have multiple pages and "field" components on each page. Multiple field components can be added on each page. Each field component will have text fields that users can edit. I would like to keep track of those values as users type, so that state is always up-to-date (like `v-model`). Multiple pages can be added as well.

I am having trouble finding a way for Vuex to keep track of the new pages and field components that users add or remove.

```js
//example of how my state looks
const state = {
    pages: [ 
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Contact Information',
            fields: [ 
                {
                    name: 'First Name',
                    type: 'text-field',
                    required: true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Activities',
            fields: [ 
                {
                    name: 'Summary',
                    type: 'textarea-field',
                    required: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
//pages are just tabs
<a @click="addPage">Add Page</a>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"  v-for="(page,key) in allPages" :key="key">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">
         {{page.name}}
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>

//example of how the field html looks
<div class="tab-pane" v-for="(page, key) in allPages" :key="key">
     <div v-for="(field, key) in page.fields" :key="key">
          <page-field :value="field.name" :type="field.type"/>
     </div>
     <a @click="addField">Add Field</a>
</div>

//field component example
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text"> //I want to keep track of this input with Vuex every time a new field component is added
</div>
</template>
```

Any time a new page or field component is added; or when someone types in the text field inside the field component, I want my state to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `input`-event handler that invokes a Vuex mutation to set the page field...

1. In the store, update the `fields` array-element to contain a `value` property, which will hold the user input:

```js
/* store.js */
const state = {
  pages: [
    {
      // ...
      fields: [
        {
          // ...
          value: null 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      // ...
      fields: [
        {
          // ...
          value: null 
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Also add a Vuex mutation that sets the page field:

```js
/* store.js */
const mutations = {
  SET_PAGE_FIELD(state, { pageId, fieldName, fieldValue }) {
    const page = state.pages.find(page => page.id === pageId)
    if (page) {
      const field = page.fields.find(field => field.name === fieldName)
      if (field) {
        field.value = fieldValue
      }
    }
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations 
})
```

3. Update `page-field`'s input elements to emit an `input` event with the target value:

```html
/* PageField.vue */
<template>
  <div class="page-field">
    <input @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" ...> 
    <textarea @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" .../> 
  </div>
</template>
```

4. Handle the `input` event in the parent by mutating the page field in the store (via the mutation in step 2):

```html
/* App.vue */
<template>
  <div class="tab-pane" v-for="page in allPages" :key="page.id">
    <div v-for="field in page.fields" :key="field.name">
      <page-field
        @input="setField(page.id, field.name, $event)" 
        :type="field.type"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    setField(pageId, fieldName, fieldValue) {
      this.$store.commit('SET_PAGE_FIELD', { 
        pageId,
        fieldName,
        fieldValue
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Using v-model with Vuex state]